# Ipython notebook

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to download and convert this set into a pandas DataFrame structure and display the first 10 lines for viewing in a jupyter notebook.

```
url =  'https://ckannet-storage.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/2014-12-13T15:15:31.729Z/airfields.json'
resp = requests.get(url)
resp.content
```

I ran this and it gives me all the content how can I only limit the content so that it can display the first 10 lines only.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your response string to json and then pandas dataframe. Finally select first 10 rows from it. Code -

```
import pandas as pd
import json

j = json.loads(resp.content)
df = pd.DataFrame(j)
df[:10]
```